# How to prevent a folder to be deleted in Windows

Tags: windows-10

I want to make a folder in Windows 10 to be protected from deletion.

I am trying to protect "Downloads" folder. I tried setting rules in  Properties -> Security -> Advanced. It has no effect. I tried both adding "Deny" rule on "Delete" for "Everyone" and removing "Allow" on "Delete" in existing rules. After doing those changes I was able to delete folder. Popup menu shows "Administrator" icon next to the "Delete" button, but there is no confirmation dialog, when I press it.

I know that there are many similar questions here but none of them has a solution (except placing a binary into the folder and making sure that it runs all the time).

Comment: It’s virtually impossible to prevent a file or folder from being deleted by an Administrator.  Can you provide the ACL for the folder and the permissions for those users and user groups that have access to the folder by editing your question

Comment: An admin user will always be able to delete a folder.  You can take many steps to prevent an admin from deleting a folder, but they will be able to undo those steps if they know how.

Comment: I have just a default Windows setup with the normal Downloads folder. I want to protect it from accidental move with a mouse or an easy deletion with Delete button.

Answer (score 2):

Some [ways to prevent deletion](https://www.tunesbro.com/prevent-file-folder-being-deleted.html):

- Modify ownership of the folder.

  - Right-clik the folder and select *Properties*.
  - On the *Security* tab, select *Advanced*.
  - On the *Permissions* tab, *Disable inheritance*, removing all inherited permissions.
  - This denies permission to do **anything** to that folder, until you assign an owner and set permissions for that owner. Of course, that owner should be able to delete the folder... so you might want to create a new user for that purpose.
- Use third-party software, such as *TunesBro Folder Unbreak* or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/folder-protect/). **N.B.** Check reviews and use [VirsuTtoal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to look for malware before installing any software.

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a try: and as you said, I wasn't able to do anything with that folder at all. I tried giving me permissions (Full Control for "Subfolders and files only" and some of the permissions for "This folder only") while making another user as owner. I almost achieved what I wanted. Now, when trying to delete or move the directory it would ask for admin permissions. It's no ideal because I am still able to press Shift + Del, then Enter and Enter again and delete it completely...

Comment: The steps from the link are pretty much useless as it will protect the folder from accidental deletion, but also any usage of that folder by any user :o)